# login history and audit trail salesforce export files encoding

Tags: setup-audit-log

We have configuration in Greek letters (users as well as some profile names etc)
I go to setup -> View setup audit trail and when i download the csv of audit trail for the last 6 months, the CSV is with " ???????? " when it should have Greek letters. The same with login history. Is there a way to configure the encoding of the file of somehow to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this was proposed as an idea but did not get enough votes enough to be considered. [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnaCAAS) is the link for the idea url.

However it appears if you get Setup Audit records from workbench, downloaded csv shows character as correct. You need to select Bulk CSV while doing query. After job completes you can download the result and check characters are correct. Sample query is:

```
SELECT CreatedDate,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedBy.Username,ResponsibleNamespacePrefix,Display,Section 
FROM SetupAuditTrail 
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

[image: workbench setup audit query screenshot]